# How to call node js API from domain in aws ec2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2

I have setup apache and node in my AWS ec2 instance. And I have an associate domain and SSL certificate also to this instance.

Now when I call PHP API from the domain it works perfectly, but when I call node js API it does not work. but it works when I call from IP address.

for example,

when I call like below it works perfectly

```
http://<ip>:3000/get-messages
```

But when I call like this It is not working

```
https://<domain>:3000/get-messages
```

OR

```
https://<domain>/get-messages
```

How can I get my nod js APIs from the domain?

Comment: If the domain points to the correct ip, then the only difference is the usage of `http` vs `https`. Does `http://<domain>:3000` work?

Comment: No, only node js APIs are not working, PHP APIs are working in the domain with https.

Comment: Ok if `http://<domain>:3000` does _not_ work, and `http://<ip>:3000` _does_ work, then there's only one possible reason left: your DNS is not set up correctly.

Comment: This could be on 2 possible sides: Where you set up DNS for your domain has the wrong ip, or no ip at all (or no CNAME, etc.).. or: from the system where you are trying to call the API DNS is not set up correctly. It would also really help if you shared the actual error.